# Navigating to specific page on push notification click

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I am working with xamarin forms. In Xamarin Android I received the notification when app not in foregroud/backgroud (i.e killed the app). When clicking on the notification I need to navigate to specific page.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            string notificationMessage = intent.GetStringExtra(Constants.MESSAGE);
            string notificationThreadId = intent.GetStringExtra(Constants.MESSAGE_THREAD_ID);
            bool isFromNotificaion = true;
            PushNotificationLog notificationLog = new PushNotificationLog(notificationMessage, notificationThreadId, isFromNotificaion);
            ConferenceMobileApp.App app = new App(notificationLog);
            LoadApplication(app);
        }
```

The OnNewIntent is called when app in foreground or background , not when app is killed.

And my notification send code is below

```
void SendNotification(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            string messageBody = "";
            string messageThreadId = "";
            message.Data.TryGetValue(MESSAGE,out messageBody);
            message.Data.TryGetValue(MESSAGE_THREAD_ID, out messageThreadId);
            string messageLogId = "0";//message.Data.TryGetValue(MESSAGE_LOG_ID);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            intent.PutExtra(MESSAGE, messageBody);
            intent.PutExtra(MESSAGE_THREAD_ID, messageThreadId);
            //intent.PutExtra(MESSAGE_LOG_ID, messageLogId);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);


            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this).SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .SetContentTitle("PKConf")
                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
            //setting notification id
            int notificaionId = Convert.ToInt32(messageLogId);
            notificationManager.Notify(notificaionId, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
```

How could I achieve this when app is not in foreground/background?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below events in your mainactivity.cs

```html
       protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume(); // Always call the superclass first.
        
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause(); // Always call the superclass first
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding OnResume

```
protected async override void OnResume()
{
     base.OnResume();
     // Your Code. I would guess same code as you have in OnNewIntent
}
```